# How to solve the error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\FAMILY\yoga\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\FAMILY\Downloads\yogaguru\yogaguru\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

 What went wrong:
 A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 com/android/build/api/dsl/StoreArchive

 Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 Run with --scan to get full insights.

 Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image: Screenshot]

I removed everything from the .gradle caches and also did Invalidate Caches in Android Studio and restarted it but still nothing works. Please help me out. I'm using gradle wrapper version: 7.5
Android Studio: 2022.3.1.2, Java: 11, Android Gradle Plugin: 7.2.2. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Shall you post your gradle content here

Comment: Hey, can you please provide me with your email address so I can send you my code and gradle file there so you can fix it, please?